# Blank Webview in WPF

Tags: wpf, revit-api, webview2

I want to display the web in a WPF I used webview2 and followed the [documentations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webview2/get-started/wpf)

I have checked the visibility and webview runtime and Microsoft Edge webview2 are installed but unfortunately, nothing happens.

that's the xmal code:

```
<Window
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WebViewRev01"
         xmlns:Wpf="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf" x:Class="WebViewRev01.WebViewTrial"
           xmlns:wv2="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf;assembly=Microsoft.Web.WebView2.Wpf"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800" Title="main window" >


<Grid Grid.Row="1">
    <DockPanel>
        <wv2:WebView2 Name="webView"
              Source="https://www.microsoft.com"/>
    </DockPanel>
</Grid>
```

and that's the code behind:

```
public partial class WebViewTrial : Window
{
    public WebViewTrial()
    {
        
        InitializeComponent();
        
    }
}
```

[Image of blank window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAOkL.png)

Update

The code doesn't work when I implement it as plugin in Revit but it works fine outside Revit

Comment: Your code as you've posted it works fine, so there has to be something else going on. Is there anything interesting in the debug output console?